# Following crash, built-in keyboard and trackpad don't work when booted normally?

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, hardware

I was using Atom IDE when my Acer Aspire crashed. Upon reboot, I discovered my trackpad and keyboard no longer worked. External USB and keyboard work fine. Visiting the recovery menu revealed the keyboard still worked, just not for a normal boot?

Update: fn + F6 dims the screen so some functionality remains? Very odd.

Is it possible with Acers to disable the keyboard at boot [like with dell](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=286484&start=20)? Can I re-enable it or perhaps re-download the drivers?

When rebooting the laptop briefly gave a message about orphaned nodes, related I assume to the crash.

---

**Edits:** Things Tried so Far

**1)**

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

-- *no effect*

**2)**

```
discover -v --type-summary --enable-bus all
```

-- *no effect*

**3)**

Boot in safe mode and select fsck...

```
/lib/recovery-mode/recover-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.34
/dev/sda2 is mounted
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Comment: Would use recovery option in grub and drop down one kernel and see if keyboard works.  Have same problem when updated to 5.4.0-44 kernel on acer.

Comment: Can also try this  ```sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, that command didn't work. When it comes to changing the kernel is this quite straight forward or do I need to google for a 'tutorial' of sorts?

Comment: When starting grub should show, instead of picking first option, select recovery and pick a kernel listed.

Comment: If handy, a wireless keyboard should work, a USB keyboard might also but not tested.

Comment: @crip659 changing kernels worked. If you put this as an answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks man.

Comment: Not really an answer, more of a way to get keyboard working without fixing the main problem.  Something in most recent kernels is blocking keyboard, at least on acers.

Answer (score 0):

I noted you mentioned orphaned nodes. `fsck` you may wish to do that.

This is another idea. If using Ubuntu try the

```
discover
```

command to make it find you keyboard again.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/discover.1.html

Sorry I have forgotten all the variables but this link will tell you how to use it.

Then I believe Ubuntu should recognize and set it up again.

Comment: Forgive me I'm a bit out of my depth. I used `discover -v --type-summary --enable-bus all` however my problem remains. Using fsck in the recovery menu returns `/dev/sda2 is mounted` `e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.`. What should this tell me?

Comment: Think fsck should be used on unmounted partitions.  Boot from USB installer and use 'try ubuntu' and use fsck.